# $A_0 + zA_1 = \Sigma D(z) \Sigma^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A_0, A_1$ be two square symmetric  matrix over real numbers.

Consider $A_0 + zA_1$, where $z$ is a real number.
Assume also that $A_0 + zA_1 = S(z)S(z)^t.$

I would like to know if I can write it as $$A_0 + zA_1 = \Sigma D(z) \Sigma^t, $$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

I will post my ideas on the subject.

---

Imagine I can do so, then I say I can tell what the matrix $D$ is, in fact: $$A_0 + zA_1 = \Sigma D(z) \Sigma^t \Rightarrow A_1 = \Sigma D'(z) \Sigma^t, $$ so that $D'$ must be the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A_1$.

---

Clearly we can do the following:

$$A_0 + zA_1 = \Sigma(z) D(z) \Sigma(z)^t,  $$

now if one take the determinant of these two matrix one gets $$p(z) = \det(\Sigma(z))^2q(z), $$

but both $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of grade $n$, so that $\Sigma$ would be a very strange matrix.

---

Write  $$A_0 + zA_1 = A_0 + \Sigma zT \Sigma^t, $$ where $T$ contains eigenvalues of $A_1$.

There are matrices such that $A_0 = QCQ^t = \Sigma \Sigma^{-1}QCQ^t \Sigma^{-1t}\Sigma^t$, where C is diagonal.

Taking all together it looks like one has $\Sigma^{-1}Q$ to be diagonal as a sufficient (and necessary?) condition.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is to be held fixed then I don't think this can be done, however it seems quite plausible (even then) if $A_0$ and $A_1$ commute.

Comment: The elements of $D(z)$ can be something else than polynomials, i.e. algebraic functions, you are essentially considering a parametric diagonalization / Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: Can you expand?

Comment: @Ivan: a Cholesky or LDL decomposition for a positive-definite symmetric matrix is always possible, but I would not expect the entries of $D$ to be polynomials, simply.

Comment: Can you link a proof?